# Arithmetic operator overloading of stl container

Tags: c++

I'm trying to overload the arithmetic operators for a vector in the std library.

As an example, I have this for '+' and '+=':

```
vector<Complex> operator+(vector<Complex> lhs, const vector<Complex>& rhs)
{
    lhs += rhs;  // reuse compound assignment
    return lhs;
}

vector<Complex>& operator+=(vector<Complex>& lhs, const vector<Complex>& rhs)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < lhs.size(); i++)
    {
        lhs[i] += rhs[i];
    }
    return lhs;
}
```

Which I'm using in another function as follows:

```
void Matrix::rowReplace(const int r1, const int r2, const Complex& factor)
{
    vector<Complex> t1 = _rows[r2];
    // t1 *= factor; // I want to use this too, but for simplicity...
    _rows[r1] += t1;
}
```

When I try to compile I get the following error:

```
error C2676: binary '+=': '_Ty' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
       with
       [
           _Ty=std::vector<Complex,std::allocator<Complex>>
       ]
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [overloading \*, +, -'operators for vector<double> class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420209/overloading-operators-for-vectordouble-class)

Comment: I think it might... I need to go through it.  Thx

Comment: So I don't think so, but maybe... In this question the author was trying to inherit from std::vector.  I'm not doing that.  I'm implementing a vector of vectors as a matrix and I want to define some row operators on my matrix class by doing some simple operations with the vector<Complex>.  I don't have to do it through operator overloading but I think it should be doable.

Comment: What type is the error message saying `_Ty` is exactly? Is it complaining about `vector<Complex>` or `Complex` itself? Also, make sure `operator+=` is defined before `operator+`. Also, `operator+=` is not validating that `rhs` has at least as many elements as `lhs`, so the loop could go out of bounds.

Comment: Is `+=` defined for the `Complex` type?

Comment: Order was everything!  I needed to fix the order on the operators as @Remy suggested as well as move them both before they were needed in my Matrix member functions.  Thx!

Comment: "Error C2676" is what Visual Studio shows in the Error pane, but confusingly, that only shows _summaries_ of errors. If you view the Output pane, you can view the full error message. please post the full error here.

Comment: So I'm good now but I thought I'd paste the error message as suggested by @Mooing Duck in case others want to search by similar issues:   binary '+=': '_Ty' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
with
[_Ty=std::vector<Complex,std::allocator<Complex>>]

Comment: @EricStimpson: Let me clarify: Please put all important information in the question itself, including the full error message. Please don't put it in the comments, which can be and often are deleted.